# Prove it is not a closed Curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, plane-curves

I wanna prove that $(cos(t^3+t),sin(t^3+t))=γ(t)$ which is a reparametrization of a circle .Is not a closed curve like the circle. WHat i did is take this problem to the Complex plane so $$γ(t)--->e^{i(x^3+x)}$$ .So now i wanna prove that this exponentail function is not a closed curve.I can see the graph that it is not but i can find  arguments on how to say it rigorously. The definition the book has for a closed Curve is That if a curve is T-periodic  and not constant then it is closed.(using Andrew Pressleys Diff. Geometry)

Comment: Is there any restricted conditions for the variance t ?

Comment: What definition of closed curve are you using?

Comment: nope.Let  t  be  among (-00,+00)

Comment: Edited it so it is more clear.

Comment: you mean T-periodic ? $t^3+t$ is not a periodical function.

Comment: i want to prove that the whole function is not periodic not just the just $t^3+t$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a proof by contradiction.  Suppose that the curve *is* $T$-periodic.  Then there exists a $T \neq 0$ such that for all $t$, $$ \exp\left[i[(t+T)^3 + t + T\right] = \exp\left[i (t^3 + t)\right] \Rightarrow \exp\left[i(3tT^2 + 3 t^2 T + T^3 + T) \right] = 1.$$

Since this looks like a homework-type problem, I'll leave it here, but if this is just for your own edification and you can't figure out how to proceed, then let me know in the comments and I'll carry the proof further.

Comment: I found where i was mistaken I did the same thing But i was doing this.$ exp[i[(t^3+t+T)].$ Did not know i have to add T for every t. How do you know how may times you have to add T?.I think i can find out the rest myself thnks

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis:  You have to replace $t$ with $t+T$ everywhere it appears.  So $t^3$ becomes $(t+T)^3$, $\cos t$ would become $\cos (t+T)$, and so forth.

Comment: All i have to do is to find roots of the polynomial  T so it is zero right?Because i have little knowledge of complex .

Comment: Since $e^{2in\pi} = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, you have to have $3Tt^2 + 3 T^2 t + T^3 + T = 2 n \pi$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ but for _all_ $t$.  Remember also that we're assuming that $T$ exists and has some fixed value.